# arcpy.da.SearchCursor feature orders mixed up in Oracle enterprise geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor, oracle-dbms

Something very weird happen when I use a SearchCursor over a feature class in an Oracle Enterprise Geodatabase

The order of the features in the SeachCursors changes depending of the `field_names` parameter that is used.

For instance:

```
source = "\\\\cnatrtd8\\geo\\ArcGIS Server\\Connections\\GEODEV011.sde\\GEO09E01_CS_FRA_GEN"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(source, ["OBJECTID"]) as cursor:
    ids = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    print(ids)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(source, ["OBJECTID", "CD_CS_FRA"]) as cursor:
    ids = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    print(ids)

>>>
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
[39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 54, 57, 58, 59, 60]
>>>‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

This happen with many different features class, but only in the Enterprise Geodabase. The same features class in a File geodatabase dont do this.

What could be the cause of that?

Comment: IIRC (if I remember correctly), you're never guaranteed to get back the same order of objects in a DBMS.

Comment: You've  got two issues here: 1) You can't be sure the features are physically ordered in objectid order to begin with, and 2) The database software is not required to return rows in any particular order *unless* you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle decides how to implement the query based on complex series of rules and optimizations. Indexes, order of most recent edits and versioning will all affect how the oracle query optimizer parses the query and returns the data. If you need the data to be in a specific order add a [sql_clause](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) parameter such as 'order by ObjectID'

Comment: Ok, your answer make a lot of sense. I though I would be able to speed up the queries by pre-sorting the data instead of sorting it in the query, but too bad.

Comment: You might be able to if you load it carefully and don't version it and be careful of indexes but I don't see it being worth the hassle. Instead I would make sure to index any fields that you want to sort on.

Comment: No, the index should be on the thing youre going to query by. You generally just have to suck it up on the sort of the result set (if it's not your query key)

Comment: Ok so there is no need to create an index on the SORT BY field? right?

Comment: @Vince is right, there should absolutely be a index on the query field. But I also believe that if the optimizer finds an appropriate index on the sort fields it can skip the sort. You must still leave in the sort by parameter to guarantee the correct order but behind the scenes you might not take the performance hit. You could also try a composite index of ObjectID and CD_CS_FRA.